# Proving that a general disc is open

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the disc $D(z_{0},\,r)=\{w\in\mathbb{C}:|w-z_{0}|<r\}$. I want to show this set is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The proof presented to me is as follows:

---

Let $r_{1}, r_{2}\ge0$ such that $r_{1} = |z-z_{0}|$ so $r_{1}+r_{2}=r$. Take $0<\varepsilon<\min{(r_{1},\,r_{2})}$.

Now let $z\in D(z_{0},\,r)$ which implies that $|z-z_{0}|<r$. We must show $D(z,\,\varepsilon)\subset D(z_{0},\,r)$. Let $z_{1}\in D(z,\,\varepsilon)$ then we must show $z_{1}\in D(z_{0},\,r)$. \begin{align}|z_{1}-z_{0}| &= |z_{1}-z+z-z_{0}|\\&\le|z_{1}-z|+|z-z_{0}|\\&<\varepsilon+r_{1}.\end{align}

Now recall $0<\varepsilon<\min{(r_{1},\,r_{2})}$ so $|z_{1}-z_{0}|<r_{2}+r_{1}=r\implies z_{1}\in D(z_{0},\,r)$.

---

However I just don't quite understand why we take $\varepsilon<r_{2}$ on the last line, how do we know $\min{(r_{1}, r_{2})}=r_{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know that $\mathrm{min}(r_1, r_2) = r_2$, but you do know that $\mathrm{min}(r_1, r_2) \le r_2$ and that is all you need on the last line.

Comment: oh yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y \in B(z, r-|z-z_0|)$. Then $|y-z| < r-|z-z_0|$.

The triangle inequality gives $|y-z_0| \le |y-z|+|z-z_0| < r$, and so $y \in B(z_0,r)$.

That is, $B(z, r-|z-z_0|) \subset B(z_0,r)$.